# Wordpress add custom table in search results query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search, full-text-search

Hi Dear All, I am new to  Wordpress, and I have added a custom table in db and now, and when I search some text, it shows all results other than that specific custom table that I have added.

I want to get search results including results from that table as well, I had searched and worked a lot in my `wp-content/query.php` file but didn't got my targeted results.
 Please tell me that How can I include results from that table in my search results.

Comment: I dont know waht and how to code, to add my custom table in search results, please tell any complete solution,
I have an idea to fetch results in query.php fiel and then again there is a problem, how to append these results,